# How to calculate total price of column in angular 9?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular

I want to calculate the total price, total quantity and total counted(#) of each column.

## | Item  | Price | Quantity |

1    | Mouse | 500   |  1       |
2    | Wire  | 100   |  2       |
TI:3 |       |TP:600 | TQ:3     |  <---Required Output

My Js is not working to get required output? Help me to get it

**Html**

```
     <table class="table table-hover" *ngIf="secondTableData.length" id="sum_table">
        <thead>
         <tr class="table-primary" class="titlerow">
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let newdata of secondTableData let i=index;">
            <td class="netSn">{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{ newdata.itemName }}</td>
            <td class="netQt">{{ newdata.Quantity }}</td>
            <td class="netSum">{{ newdata.retailRate }}</td>
            
        </tr>
        <tr class="totalColumn">
            <td class="totalCol">TI:</td>  <!--I want to Diaplay Total counted #  -->
            <td></td>
            <td class="totalCol">TQ:</td>  <!--I want to Display Total Quantity  -->
            <td class="totalCol">TP:</td>  <!--I want to  Display Total Price  -->
            
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Js:**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var $dataRows = $("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");

        $dataRows.each(function () {
            $(this).find('.netSn').each(function (i) {
                totals[i] += parseInt($(this).html());
            });

            $(this).find('.netQt').each(function (i) {
                totals[i] += parseInt($(this).html());
            });

            $(this).find('.netSum').each(function (i) {
                totals[i] += parseInt($(this).html());
            });
        });
        $("#sum_table td.totalCol").each(function (i) {
            $(this).html("" + totals[i]);
        });

    });
```

**Component.ts:**

```
    //To Copy data of First table to Second table after clicking first table
  secondTableData = [];
  updateSecondTable(data) {
    let foundItem = this.secondTableData.find((item) => item.itemName === data.itemName);
    if (foundItem) {
      foundItem.Quantity += 1;
      foundItem.retailRate += data.retailRate;
      return;
    }
    this.secondTableData.push({
      itemName: data.itemName,
      Quantity: 1,
      retailRate: data.retailRate,
    })
  }
```

Comment: Either update the model or create a new model and do the calculations *inside* the component code behind file (the typescript file). Then access those new properties of the model inside the template code.

Comment: You can use reduce on tableData to create an object with accumulated data.

Comment: What should be output of first column. I think it is the index in second table right? count of no of items selected irrespecitve of quantity!

Comment: The first column should be the total row of items in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like below

### Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tfz7gz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**Template file**

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let newdata of secondTableData">
    <td>{{ newdata.Index }}</td>
    <td>{{ newdata.Item }}</td>
    <td>{{ newdata.Quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ newdata.Price }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TI : {{ secondTableData.length }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>TQ : {{ totalQuantity }}</td>
    <td>TP : {{ totalPrice }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Typescript file**

```
export class AppComponent {
  totalQuantity = 0; <-- A variable to hold quantity total
  totalPrice = 0; <-- A variable to hold price total

  updateSecondTable(data) {
    let foundItem = this.secondTableData.find((item) => item.Item === data.Item);
    if (foundItem) {
      foundItem.Quantity += 1;
      foundItem.Price += data.Price;
      this.getColumnTotal(); // <-- A call here
      return;
    }
    this.secondTableData.push({
      Index: this.secondTableData.length + 1,
      Item: data.Item,
      Quantity: 1,
      Price: data.Price,
    })
    this.getColumnTotal(); // <-- A call here
  }

  // Here is the logic
  getColumnTotal() {
    const { Quantity, Price } = this.secondTableData.reduce((acc, item) => {
      acc.Quantity += item.Quantity;
      acc.Price += item.Price;
      return acc;
    }, {
      Quantity: 0,
      Price: 0
    });
    this.totalQuantity = Quantity;
    this.totalPrice = Price;
  }
}
```